# Nodejs: Error: Cannot find module 'html'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

im using nodejs and im trying to serve only html files (no jade, ejs ... engines).

heres my entry point (index.js) code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
});
```

This is doing just fine when i hit the url "localhost:5000/", but when i try something like "localhost:5000/whatever" i got the following message: 
**Error: Cannot find module 'html'**

im new to nodejs, but i want **all** routes to render the `index.html` file. How can i do that ???

Thank you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to specify your view folder and parse the engine to HTML.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
});
```

Comment: Dont forget that you need to install "ejs" before, ok ? hugs

Comment: its working just fine after installing ejs of course, and putting the 'index.html' inside the 'views' folder, thanks mate.

Comment: @vcrzy  why it does not work if I do not install 'ejs' module, how ejs is dependent even if I have the static index.html ??? also I have only one file under public directory..

Comment: Agreed this is not the correct answer. Forcing the guy to use EJS when he had no need nor desire...

Answer (score 22):

Use render only when using a rendering engines like jade or ejs. If you want to use plain HTML, place it in the public folder or serve it as a static file.

```
res.sendFile('index2.html', {root : __dirname + '/views'});
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all you need to install ejs engine. For that you can use the following code

```
npm install ejs
```

After that you need to add app engine and set the view directory.

The changed code is given below,

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
});
```