# ui-router can't load state if reload it

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

A have an app with ui-router and I have a problem if I reload a page (state).
Example: app root path '/' and state registration '/registration' if I go to link '/registration', loads registration page, then I refresh page and get:

> Cannot GET /registration

I know this problem and use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

But it doesn't solve my problem.

My app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngCookies',
    'myApp.main',
    'myApp.navbar',
    'myApp.registration',
    'myApp.login',
    'myApp.newOrder',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
]);

app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'templates/content/main.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl'
        })
        .state('registration', {
            url: '/registration',
            templateUrl: 'templates/content/registration.html',
            controller: 'registrationCtrl'
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'templates/content/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        })
        .state('new-order', {
            url: '/new-order',
            templateUrl: 'templates/content/newOrder.html',
            controller: 'newOrderCtrl'
        });
}]);
```

index.html use:

```
<base href="/">
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the 'Cannot GET /registration' because:

> This is because when you submit the link it makes a request to that
>   route on the server, when angular is using client side routing. To
>   enable html5 mode, you need to serve the index on all routes for html5
>   mode. Like this for a node app.

[Link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/372) to the topic with answer.

Then I got same error as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779846/nodejs-error-cannot-find-module-html)

And now all works perfect.